# How does Chrome handle videos stored in memory?

Tags: html, google-chrome, electron

Im building an application with Electron.  My application has hundreds of videos that are activated using the basic HTML5 video play and pause functions.  The app sometimes uses as much as 8gb of memory.  This is fine for me because I have 16gb of ram, but I am unsure what would happen on a computer with less ram.

Would my application crash on a system with less ram, or does Chrome automatically delete videos out of the memory to make space? If so, how does it choose which videos to delete? Is this what is known as "garbage collection"?

Comment: You can test what happens by setting up a VM, perhaps using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and allocating a small amount of RAM to it. The memory cleanup is most probably not directly related to GC but rather Chrome storing recently played videos in a buffer so they can be replayed without re-downloading - which would be dynamically managed by Chrome based on the amount of available RAM.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will try it.  I realized now it must be an issue with electron, because when I open the application a chrome browser it stays around 2gb of memory, meaning it is being managed properly, but in electron it continually rises.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Didn't found anything that helps. I tried `webFrame.clearCache()` and it seems to waste much more less RAM but after some time is increasing anyway :( maybe you will have more luck clearing webFrame cache.

Comment: @Genar I found this while looking around: http://seenaburns.com/debugging-electron-memory-usage/  

It seems he had the same problem.  It looks like its just how Electron handles memory management; it eats up memory until its forced not to.